# Method for double integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I go about solving double integrals of this type :

$$I = \int_0^π dx \int_y^π x^4 \sin(yx^2)~ \mathrm dy$$

I just need some direction or a full answer I can follow?

Comment: Is your real question how to integrate things of the form $x^4\sin (ax^2)$ with respect to $x$? Because that's the hard part.

Comment: The limits of integration can't involve the differential.  $x$ is a limit of your $dx$ integral.

Comment: @TheCount yes but instead of a constant $a$ I have a variable $y$

Comment: From the point of view of the first integral as you had originally written it, $y$ *is* a constant. That's a good conceptual point to grasp. It is now a totally different question....

Answer (score 0):

Change order of integration. $I=\int_0^x x^4dx\int_0^xsin(yx^2)dy=\int_0^x x^4\frac{1-cos(x^3)}{x^2}dx$.  Let $u=x^3$. Then $I=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^x(1-cos(u))du=\frac{1}{3}(x^3-sin(x^3))$.

For clarity you should use different symbols for variables of integration and integration limits, when they are not the same.

Comment: I changed the limits to π and $y$

Comment: Changing the limit to $\pi$ looks strange.  The final answer would then be $\frac{1}{3}(\pi^3-sin(\pi^3))$.